# Why BottomNavigation show in the next page in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I want to do navigation with `Scaffold` and `BottomNavigation` in Jetpack Compose. They are in the **MainPage**. But when I click the content in the **MainPage** and navigate to **DetailPage**, the `BottomNavigation` also exist, like the image:

[image: this is MainPage with BottomNavigation]

[image: this is DetailPage navigated from MainPage]

How can I hide the `BottomNavigation` in the **DetailPage**?

Comment: Please add source code of your Scaffold

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which screens you want to show and which screens you dont want; Otherwise it will show to all the screens inside `Scaffold`'s body (which you have `bottomBar`). The code below was from my app.

**Create a state which observes any destination changes on the navController**

Inside `when` you can put any screens that you want to show `navigationBar` else just set `currentScreen` to `NoBottomBar`

```
@Composable
private fun NavController.currentScreen(): State<MainSubScreen> {
    val currentScreen = remember { mutableStateOf<MainSubScreen>(MainSubScreen.Home) }

    DisposableEffect(key1 = this) {
        val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when {
                destination.hierarchy.any { it.route == MainSubScreen.Home.route } -> {
                    currentScreen.value = MainSubScreen.Home
                } else -> currentScreen.value = MainSubScreen.NoBottomBar
            }
        }
        addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
    }
    return currentScreen
}
```

**On the Scaffold where you put ur bottomBar**

so you can check if `currentScreen` was `NoBottomBar` if it was, don't show it

```
// initialized currentScreeen above
val currentScreen by navController.currentScreen()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            if (currentScreen != MainSubScreen.NoBottomBar) {
                MainBottomNavigation()
            } else Unit
        }
    ) {
        // Your screen
    }
```

Comment: It`s a good way. But I complete it by saving a state by ViewModel. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you put your NavHost. If it wraps your Scaffold then you navigate that Composable covers entire screen

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "start_destination"
) {
     composable(route = "start_destination") { ->
        Scaffold(){...}
    }
}
```

If NavHost is inside `content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit`, when you navigate while your `TopAbbpar`, `Tabs` or `BottomNavigation` remains on screen

Comment: I think this way against the intention of Scaffold.So I complete it by saving a state by ViewModel. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fond a way to do it.
Try to use ViewModle to controll the visibility of BottomNavigation, show it when enter to MainPage and hide it when leave MainPage

```
// ViewModel
class VM: ViewModel() {
  private val _state: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(true)
  val state: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _state
  fun setState(status: Boolean) {
      _state.postValue(status)
  }
}


// MainPage
@Compose MainPage(vm: VM) {
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    vm.setState(true)
  }

  DisposableEffect(key1 = true) {
    onDispose {
      vm.setState(false)
    }
  }
}


// page contains Scaffold
@Composable
fun Greeting(vm: VM) {
  // State of BottomNavigation`s visibility
  val state = remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean>(true) }
  // read the BottomNavigation`s visibility from ViewModel and send to State
  vm.state.observeAsState().value?.let { state.value = it }

  Scaffold(bottomBar = {
    // show / hide BottomNavigation controlled by State
    state.takeIf { it.value }?.let {
        BottomNavigation {
            list.forEachIndexed { index, label ->
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    label = { Text(text = label) },
                    selected = index == selectedItem.value,
                    onClick = { selectedItem.value = index },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
    }
  }) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "one") {
        composable(route = "one") { PageList(navController, vm) }
        composable(route = "detail") { PageDetail(vm) }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you want ot hide the BottomNavigation quickly, you can hide BottomNavigation before Navigation.